# Calculating numbers that are big decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Could someone explain me how can I use Big Decimal in Java?
I created a new big Decimal that has 2 numbers.
I tried and searched so much but I couldn't find anything that could help me this is the only thing I found:

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("987634534563454354321,3412434534534535343214");
```

How can I make Big Decimal strings and then calculate those 2 string number's min and max using math import?

Comment: Did you look at the `BigDecimal` API?

Comment: Shouldn't that comma be a period? Or is there some locale setting that will set it?

Comment: http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial is a nice tutorial

Comment: A BigDecimal contains a single number.  If this executed successfully then you are in a locale that uses comma for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

The code above is invalid due to the comma separated numbers in the constructor of `BigDecimal`. 2 individual instances of `BigDecimal` are required.

Precision can be lost by converting `BigDecimal` values to the `int`, `float` and `double` types used by `Math.max` and `Math.min`. The [max](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#max%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method should be used instead. Another reason to use `BigDecimal` that the numbers can overflow. This is true in this case in that `987634534563454354321` and `3412434534534535343214` are greater than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Try this

```
BigDecimal big1 = new BigDecimal("987634534563454354321");
BigDecimal big2 = new BigDecimal("3412434534534535343214");
BigDecimal min = big1.min(big2);
BigDecimal max = big1.max(big2);
```

Familiarize yourself with the [javadoc for BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: what if i wanna calculate it using math import? :s its not minandmax only , i have to calculate sin , tan , and cos too :s

Comment: You will lose precision if you use Math.max. Use `BigDecimal#max` instead

Comment: well its a class work . they told me i should calculate 2 numbers using big decimal using some functions from math import . i have no idea about how to calculate strings :s

Comment: You wont be able to do that. These numbers are simply too large for `Math.min` and `Math.max` methods and the input value will overflow before they are even used by the methods

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc of [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). BigDecimal is - like String - an immutable class. So one does

```
BigDecimal c = a.add(b);
```

(`a` remains unchanged.)